# How to format a method output in ruby when calculating frequency of characters

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working on a ruby project, and I have everything working correctly, apart from getting the correct format. I need the frequency shown in, for example, `hi = {h: 1 i: 1}`. I also need the rest of the alphabet shown, even if the letter is not used. The frequency count needs to be represented by `'*' * the number of occurrences` (eg: `3 => '***'`).

For example, when using the string `'hello world!'` the frequencies are:

`{"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>2, "w"=>1, "r"=>1, "d"=>1, "!"=>1}`

This then needs to be converted, without any special characters, to:

`{A: , B: ,C: , D:* , E:* , F: , G: , H:* , I: , J: , K: , L:*** , M: , N: , O:** ,P: ,Q: , R: , S: , T: , U: , V: , W:* , X: , Y: , Z:}` (with the undefined values being something of `''` or `nil`)

Here is what I have so far:

```
def display
  calculateFrequencies
end

private

def calculateFrequencies
  #@text = "Hello World!"
  @letters = @text.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, letters|
    next if c == " "
    letters[c] +=1
  end
end
```

I have found this on a programmers discord that I was invited to and was able to get this from a person from there,

```
('a'..'z').each {|ltr| puts "%s: %s" % [ltr, '*' * h.fetch(ltr, 0)]}
```

and this works according to what I need apart from at the end of the terminal line there is the => "a".."z" I was wondering how would I go about making the last line not appear

Comment: Hint: `'*' * 3 # => "***"`

Comment: Note: Ruby is case sensitive and method names should be lower-case *only*. Capital letters are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` instances exclusively. This method should be called `calculate_frequencies` to follow that convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a range of all letters `'a'...'z'` creating an array of pairs (two element arrays): `[l.upcase,  "*" * stats.fetch(l, 0)]` and then convert it to hash with [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

[`stats.fetch(l, 0)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) returns the frequency of letters or 0, [`"*" * number`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-2A)  repeats `*` a `number`of times.

Whole code:

```
def calculateFrequencies
  #@text = "Hello World!"
  stats = @text.downcase.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c, letters|
      next if c == " "
      letters[c] +=1
  end
  @letters = ('a'..'z').map{|l| [l.upcase,  "*" * stats.fetch(l, 0)]}.to_h
end
```

Comment: In ruby 2.6, `to_h` takes map's block: `('a'..'z').to_h{|l| [l.upcase,  "*"stats.fetch(l, 0)]}`. Finally, they acknowledged this pattern.